# Drag & Drop list item position

Tags: jquery, html

I'm attempting to create a case priority list for a client, and will be using `Jquery UI` for the drag and drop feature.

The problem I am sitting with at the moment is finding out the new `Index` of the `list item` once it has been moved. I am hoping one of you has encountered this before or knows how I can get this? I am really struggling to find it.

I have tried lots of SO thread which say I should use `.index()`, but i cant seem to get it working. Please see my attempt in this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/fKvv3/16/)

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

       var Items = $("#SortMe li");

     $('#SortMe').sortable({
         disabled: false,
         axis: 'y',
         forceHelperSize: true,
         update: function () {
             var Newpos = $("li").index();
             alert("You moved item to position " + Newpos);

         }
     }).disableSelection();
 });
```

Once the `list item` has been dropped, I would like to know its new `position / index` so I can use this in `SQL` later on in the process.

Thanks so much,
Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you're doing alright, except you're targeting the wrong element. You should instead check `ui.item` for the current dragged element.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/fKvv3/17/

Comment: Awesome! :)  Thanks a lot, will accept answer when I can.