# Jquery table row index after move

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I created a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28023285/drag-drop-list-item-position) yesterday to help me find the new index of a `<tr>` or a `<li>` once it has been moved using `Jquery UI` drag & drop functionality, and this works perfectly :)

Something I did not think about however and have been trying to figure out this morning, is... How would I find the `index` of the `<tr>` or `<li>` that is being shifted up or down.

EG: Given the below table, if I Move "email" into position 1, "other" will be shifted into `index` of 2. How would I alert this value and its RefID ?

```
+--------+------------------+
| Ref ID | Issue relates to |
+--------+------------------+
|   9342 | Other            |
|   9392 | CRM              |
|   9394 | CRM              |
|   9308 | eMail            |
|   9365 | CRM              |
+--------+------------------+
```

Here is a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/fKvv3/26/) I have been playing with.

Thanks you in advance guys.

Mike

**EDIT:** So, I was just moving them around a bit more, and if you move another row above the ones we just moved, "Other" will now be in `index` 3. Yikes!! Getting more complicated for me as I look at this thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I probably didn't phrase my question correctly, but I managed to get what I wanted by just checking the `index` and `RefID` of all the `rows` after moving them.

My code now looks like this:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

     $('tbody').addClass("DragMe");

     $('.DragMe').sortable({
         disabled: false,
         axis: 'y',
         items: "> tr:not(:first)",
         forceHelperSize: true,
         update: function (event, ui) {
             var Newpos = ui.item.index();
             var RefID = $('tr').find('td:first').html();


             //alert("Position " + Newpos + "..... RefID: " + RefID);
             $("#GridView1 tr:has(td)").each(function () {
                 var RefID = $(this).find("td:eq(0)").html();
                 var NewPosition = $("tr").index(this);
                     alert(RefID + " " + NewPosition);

             });

         }
     }).disableSelection();
 });
```

And here is the working [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/fKvv3/28/)

Thank for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `:eq()` selector to target only required tr element.

```
var RefID = $('tr').eq(Newpos).find('td:first').html();
var RefName = $('tr').eq(Newpos).find('td:eq(1)').html();
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cdagbp7x/)**

Comment: no need to search the DOM twice to get the row when it's already available as `ui.item`

Comment: ohh. did not saw the ref being fetched too.

Answer (score 0):

You are always getting the html from the first row , regardless of which row was moved.

Since `ui.item` is the `<tr>` that was moved , you can access the `td` by looking within `ui.item`

```
var RefID = ui.item.find('td:first').html();
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/fKvv3/27/)**</kbd>